# MySQL Query SUM Issue with POWER

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with combining POWER and SUM inside a query. I have table with structure like below:

```
Name    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
Ayam    1000    5   350 100 350
Bebek   1000    5   350 100 350
Kuda    1000    5   350 100 350
```

And my query is like below:

```
$query = "SELECT 
    POWER(c1, -$c1) * 
    POWER(c2, $c2) * 
    POWER(c3, -$c3) * 
    POWER(c4, -$c4) * 
    POWER(c5, $c5)
    /
    SUM(
        POWER(c1, -$c1) * 
        POWER(c2, $c2) * 
        POWER(c3, -$c3) * 
        POWER(c4, -$c4) * 
        POWER(c5, $c5)
    )
    AS TOTAL

FROM `table`";
```

But current query only give me one result, even though i have multiple records in database. If i try to remove **SUM**, the result is normal but i need result with **SUM**.

So, anyone can help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can only use SUM in combination with GROUP BY

Comment: Why do you have a * at the end of both power sections?

Comment: Ignore * at the end of POWER, typo here. So, i can't use POWER with SUM?

Comment: @xander, agreed.  I think SUM is an aggregate function.

Comment: @Bluebaron I get it as he multiplies powers, then divides it by sum of multiplied powers. Makes no sense to me tbh.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out, but, I think wants the sum of all those AND the data that went to make it.  He really wants two separate select statements.

Comment: @Ali answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a96b/4 returns 3 lines to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a group by:

```
SELECT 
    POWER(c1, -$c1) * 
    POWER(c2, $c2) * 
    POWER(c3, -$c3) * 
    POWER(c4, -$c4) * 
    POWER(c5, $c5) * 
    /
    SUM(
        POWER(c1, -$c1) * 
        POWER(c2, $c2) * 
        POWER(c3, -$c3) * 
        POWER(c4, -$c4) * 
        POWER(c5, $c5) * 
    )
    AS TOTAL

FROM `table`
GROUP BY Name
```